# Vue.js, async await functions return empty results

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, babeljs, core-js

js project where I need to use await/async for getting data from my API.

My code

```
        const logsFc = async () => {
          let logs = [];
          for (let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
            const formData = new FormData();

            const getLogsFc = () => {
              getLogs.request(new URLSearchParams(formData), (response) => {
                if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
                  localConsoleLog('getLogs', response);
                  return response.data.data;
                }
              });
            };

            let data = await getLogsFc();
            console.warn(data);
            logs.concat(data);
          }

          return logs;
        };
```

but logs are returned before getting response.

`babel.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        useBuiltIns: 'usage',
        corejs: 3.6,
        modules: false,
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

`"vue": "^2.6.0"`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `getLogsFc` isn't returning anything. You probably want to put a `return` before `getLogs.request`.

Comment: What is `getLogs.request`? It doesn't appear to return a promise, so you cannot use `await` here.

Comment: @Bergi `getLogs.request` is `axios` request

Comment: In that case, don't pass a callback but use the promise that it creates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't run the callback of the `request` just return the response :

```
 const getLogsFc = async () => {
          let response = await getLogs.request(new URLSearchParams(formData));
            if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
                  localConsoleLog('getLogs', response);
                  return response.data.data;
                }
            };

            let data = await getLogsFc();
```

Comment: Your `response` here would be a promise and does not have a `.status` property

Comment: you're right  i forgot to ad the async/await to the inner function